# Mock [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted() using Pester?

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, testing, mocking, pester

How do I Mock `[System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted()` using Pester? I tried the following but no luck.

```
Describe "Configuration" {
    Mock [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted {
        return false
    }

    It "should mock rooted Path" {
        [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted("C:\a") | Should Be False
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer to your question is short and simple:

**You can't.**

---

According to [Pester's Github Issue #72](https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/72), the best alternative is to wrap the method call in a separate function and `Mock` this function.

There are a few discussions about this and a lot of people would love to be able to mock .Net methods, but until now, I was unable to find any solution on this. Unfortunately, even overwriting methods (independent of Pester) isn't that easy.